# Is there an explanation for these gaps?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, mordell-curves

Here :

http://www.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/BeGa-data.html

there is a complete list of the integral points of the Mordell-curves for $-10^7\le n\le 10^7$. I searched for large solutions (in particular for large solutions on curves with only $2$ integral points) and accidently found the following unusual gaps :

```
779996 2 [170,2386] [170,-2386]
787577 4 [256074644,4097791586581] [256074644,-4097791586581] [1778,74977] [1778,-74977]
794610 2 [253686159,4040593486767] [253686159,-4040593486767]
798736 2 [192536904,2671597178300] [192536904,-2671597178300]
800004 2 [-92,146] [-92,-146]
```

If I understand the database right, there are only the $5$ given numbers in the range $[779996,800004]$ , for which the Mordell-curve has an integral point. I did not check the whole list, but these gaps seem to be very large in comparison with the other gaps I noticed.

> Is there an explanation that this range has such a small number of $n$'s with integral points ? Or could this indicate an error with the database ?

Comment: Peter, I could say something, but [this MSE-user](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/59326/mike-bennett) is much more qualified!

Comment: @Mike Bennett Hi, can you explain these unusual gaps in the database ? Or is it just a coincidence ? Is it plausible that this range has only $5$ $n$'s with integral points ?

Comment: Peter, there is certainly a problem with the data -- it looks like some number of files has been omitted. I will attempt to find the fault and fix it (I'm currently in Australia without easy access to the raw files, so this might take a while). Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: It seems that some of the files got corrupted during sorting. You can take a look at http://www.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/0-10^6n-sorted.txt to see some closer-to-raw data for 0<k<10^6. I'll get this fixed by week's end

Comment: @MikeBennett Did you check the other files ? And an additional question : Why didn't you post the files in text-format ? Reading a pdf-file takes ages compared with reading a text-file and text-programs have better features to search. For example, I did not find a command to search $15$-digit (or more) numbers with the adobe reader. OK, I can convert the pfd-files in text-files ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is now fixed. The file was apparently corrupted while converting from text to pdf. Thank you again for pointing this out (I will check the other files).